# Mac Mail retrieve mail same message over and over again

Tags: email, mac, pop3

key facts:

Mac OS X v10.6.5
Mail v4.4
Retrieve messages folder in the Mail has the same message over and over again, it's 44.6MB file the computer saves again and again (1547 times) ~ 70GB.
Retrieved Messages.mbox is now 99GB

deleting messages doesn't work in the mail program(they never go into the trash, just reappear, real memory goes up to 800-900 MB

Comment: This isn't a programming question, and would get better answers on [superuser.com](http://www.superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This link should help: [Tip: Change Mail settings to save hard drive space](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20054452-263.html)

April 15, 2011 4:21 PM PDT
Tip: Change Mail settings to save hard drive space
by Joe Aimonetti

Comment: And what does the link say?